# QGIS and Mergin Maps query builder

Tags: qgis, mergin-maps

We have a QGIS project with the following GeoPackage layers:

- Projects with columns:
- Fid: int
- Description: string
- FieldworkRounds with columns:
- Fid: int
- Temperature: int
- SurveyorName: string with a default constraint that the @mergin_username value is used to populate the field upon a new feature being added.
- ProjectId: int

The project contains a association relationship from FieldworkRounds to Projects.

**What I try to achieve on Mergin Maps mobile is:**
Have surveyors only see FieldworkRound records which they themselves have added altough the projects FieldworkRounds layers contains records from other users.

**What is happening**
When I add a filter to the layer using the query builder and filter on the Temperature column, the filter works as intended. In Mergin Maps on mobile only the FieldworkRounds are displayed which adhere to the filter.
When I add a filter to the layer as follows:

SurveyorName = @mergin_username

then the layer appears empty.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It appears that during filtering the value @mergin_username is null.
When during filtering you use "@mergin_username is null" the filter returns results.